# linker error using qmake with boost thread in windows MSVC

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++, boost-thread, qmake

I am using QtCreator on Windows with boost library. right now I am stuck with linking boost threading library against my Application.
In my `C:\boost_1_47_0\bin.v2\libs\thread\build` directory I see only `msvc-10.0` no `mingw` So I need to choose `MSVC2010` as My build configuration instead of mingw.

on compilation its reporting error:
 `LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib'`

I can find There is `boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib` here in libs directory but no `libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib` *(check the extra `lib` on left)*

in my `.pro`

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:\boost\include\boost-1_47
win32:CONFIG(debug): LIBS += C:\boost_1_47_0\bin.v2\libs\thread\build\msvc-10.0\debug\threading-multi\boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib
```

Comment: i'm tempted to believe the "missing lib file" might have been indicated using compiler macros. Have you tried seeing whether the error message depends on the "LIBS +=" statement in your pro file? (e.g. deliberately put a mis-spelt file name)

Comment: My observation with QT is that you have to specify the LIBS parameter in the .pro file differently when you are using MSVC as the underlying compiler.

Comment: checked. deliberately misspeling the `LIBS` value reports `cannot open file` Linker error with the same `misspelled` file path. So It seems compiler obeying the LIBS directive.

Comment: have you tried the 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib' in c:/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib? (present in my 1_49_0 build)

Comment: There is no such `stage` directory

Comment: did your build proceed without issues? or are you using a pre-built boost?

Comment: No there was no issues. In My Windows I ran `bootstrap.bat` to install boost

Comment: you need to then build using bjam.